# PHP and rrd : rrd_xport function returning error

Tags: php, rrdtool, rrd

I'm trying to use the rrd_xport function to read data from an RRD file.
The function rrd_xport takes an array with 'options' as argument, but for the life of me I can't get it to work. It doesn't help that the function is undocumented. All I get out of it is "rrd_xport failed".

Can anyone provide me with a simple example of what it expects in the array ?

Here is a code snippet:

```
$options = Array(
  "start" => "now-1d",
  "end" => "now",
  "step" => 1,
  "def" => Array(
    "vname" => 'connections_vname',
    "file" => 'data.rrd',
    "dsname" => 'connections',
    "cfunc" => 'MAX'
  ),
  "xport" => Array(
    'vname' => 'connections_vname',
    'legend' => 'legend'
  ),
);

print_r(rrd_xport($options));
```

Edit:

It appears it is expecting the array to be in a format like this:

```
                $options = array(
                         "--step", "60",
                         "--start", "-1 year",
                         "DEF:out=data.rrd:outoctets:AVERAGE",
                         'XPORT:out:"foo"',
                 );
```

I've straced the script running from the command-line and atleast it's reading the rrd file now. Still no dice though.

Edit 2:

Solved the issue! For future reference, the rrd_xport functions expects an array in the following format:

```
$options = Array(
  "--step", "1",
  "--start", "-1 year",
  "--end", "now",
  "DEF:out=<filename>:<name of your DS>:AVERAGE",
  'XPORT:out:"<legend>"',
);
```

XPORT and DEF are case sensitive. Hope it'll be useful to others!

Kind regards,

Dennis, i3D.net

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code you already have (if any)?

Comment: Thank you for your welcome. I've added a codesnippet to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue! For future reference, the rrd_xport functions expects an array in the following format:

```
$options = Array(
  "--step", "1",
  "--start", "-1 year",
  "--end", "now",
  "DEF:out=<filename>:<name of your DS>:AVERAGE",
  'XPORT:out:"<legend>"',
);
```